# Highlight list of words in the document using jQuery & java

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I am using know the following code to highlight specific word in the document

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('h1').highlight('word1');
      });
</script>
```

it works fine just to highlight one word !!

but I have an arrylist in my program which is written in java 
ArrayList wordsList ;

I do not know how to make it I wrote the following

```
<script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
          for (int y=0;y<wordslist.size();y++) 
          { 
         $('h1').highlight(wordslist.get(y));
          }
     });
</script>
```

it does not work , this does not highlight the words in the list

Comment: Can you do an `alert(wordslist.get(y))` in your for loop to see if your ArrayList data structure is working as expected? Or even better if you have FireBug, use `console.log(wordslist.get(y))` and go to the FireBug console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `<% %>` for your Java code:

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
         <% for (int y=0;y<wordslist.size();y++) 
          { %> 
         $('h1').highlight('<%= wordslist.get(y) %>');
        <%  } %>
     });
</script>
```

Comment: You must also put quotes around the word ($('h1').highlight('<%= wordslist.get(y) %>');), to make it valid JavaScript code (and escape the words to make sure the generated JavaScript is valid)

Answer (score 0):

wordsList is a Java variable. It's usable only at server-side. You need to iterate it at client-side, where JavaScript is executed. You thus need to transform the Java variable into JavaScript code :

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() { 
     var javaScriptWordList = [
         <c:forEach var="word" items="${wordList}">'${word}', </c:forEach> // JSP : server-side
     ];  
     for (var i = 0; i < javaScriptWordList.length; i++) {
         $('h1').highlight(javaScriptWordList[i]);
     }
 });
</script>
```

Once this JSP is executed, if the Java wordList contains "hello", "world", the generated HTML will look like this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
     var javaScriptWordList = [
         'hello', 'world',
     ];
     for (var i = 0; i < javaScriptWordList.length; i++) {
         $('h1').highlight(javaScriptWordList[i]);
     } 
 });
</script>
```

Note however that you should certainly escape the words inside the list, in case they contain characters which would make the JavaScript code invalid (for example, if one of the word is O'Reilly). Look at commons-lang [StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJavaScript%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Hi what about if I use Jsoup to append the script to the page what I mean is the script is embedded to my jsp page using Jsoup as follows: head.append("<script> $(document).ready(function(){"
         + "$('*').highlight('word1');"
        + " });"
        + "</script>"

Comment: what do you think how to make the script that is embedded be able to deal with server code

Comment: do you think I need to post another thread to discuss that since I have a jsp page that read a web page and insert the script to that web page

Comment: Whatever the solution used to generate the JavaScript code, you must make sure that the generated JavaScript is valid JavaScript. And this JavaSCrip can only use JavaScript variables : it's executed at client-side, in the user's browser, where Java doesn't exist, long after your Java variables have disappeared.